# How can i write the square root (√) in a python string?

Tags: python

I am trying to right the proof of the quadratic formula in a python step by step and am able to do the squares within the problem by doing \u00b2 but am not sure if there is a way of doing something similar with the square root.

I have searched around but am unable to find an answer and am trying to write in python the √b^2-4ac/  √4a^2 which can then by simplified to just the square root on the top and 2a on the bottom

Comment: `print('√b^2-4ac/ √4a^2)` ? Why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: At least on my machine `print('√b^2-4ac/ √4a^2')` is no problem. Could you explain what goes wrong when you do that?

Comment: thank you i will use that was just wondering if it was possible to have the square root go over everything just to make it look better.

Comment: You have a few approaches (depending on your environment). If you are printing to a terminal, you either use an plain text representation of the equation or generate an image of the equation. If you are using a Jupyter notebook, easier to just add the equation to the notebook using a LaTeX representation of the equation.

Comment: Alternative build the equation in SymPy and use the preview function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unicodes when printing strings

`print("\U0000221A")`